# CMake and external dependency

Tags: c++, cmake, leptonica

I'd like to add an external dependency to my project. The one I'm trying to add is the [Leptonica](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica) library as a submodule.

My project has the following directory structure:

|root
   CMakeLists.txt
   |-bin
   |-build
   |-buildsystem
   |-executable
   |-leptonica
   |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--cmake
   |---Configure.cmake
   |-production

In my root `CMakeLists.txt` file I added 
*ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${ROOT_DIR}/leptonica)*

Unfortunately, CMake is not searching for `Configure.cmake` in the proper directory:

```
CMake Error at leptonica/CMakeLists.txt:107 (include):

include could not find load file:

Configure

CMake Error: File

<root>/cmake/templates/LeptonicaConfig-version.cmake.in does not exist.

CMake Error at leptonica/CMakeLists.txt:113 (configure_file):

configure_file Problem configuring file
```

When I build the project by myself, everything goes fine. In my opinion, the problem is with `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`. When using `add_subdirectory` it has the value of `ROOT` CMake instead `ROOT/leptonica`, so it's searching the wrong paths - as you can see in Leptonica CMake, it's used to determinate paths of its files.

What should be the proper way to fix this - should I set `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` to `ROOT/leptonica` just before calling `add_subdirectory` and set it back when it's finished, or does some other, more elegant solutions exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every CMake project is suitable for inclusion via `add_subdirectory`.

Among those are projects which uses `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` or `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` variables.

However, inclusion via `ExternalProject_Add` (optionally wrapped with `execute_process`) always works.

---

Modifying variable `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` (and `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` too) is a **bad idea**: this variable should be changed only by CMake itself. Otherwise you may get weird errors.

Instead, you may replace (*automatically*, with some script) all references to the variable with another variable, which is not used in the project. This new variable you may *safely* set before stepping into the subproject.

Answer (score 1):

`${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` are set relative to the top-level CMakeLists.txt.  If you need something relative to your current CMakeLists.txt (leptonica), use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`.

If you're having trouble finding a cmake file like `LeptonicaConfig-version.cmake.in`, try appending the appropriate directory to `${CMAKE_MODULE_DIR}`.

```
list(APPEND ${CMAKE_MODULE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/templates)
```

I prefer to use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` over `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` any day because using the latter will break your build if you try to integrate it into a super-build later.  If I need to pass my current top-level directory to subdirectories, then I do the following and use that later down the chain.

```
set( LEPTONICA_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
```